# Weird results while printing elements of integer array

Tags: arrays, c, integer, numbers

I just have to make a simple program, where I have an array given with random numbers, then I have to do some things with the array and then print the elements at the end. But I don't know what's happening here.

First I wanted to make a code, just to print the elements and see if it works before doing anything else.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int nums[] = {12, 3, 54, -4, 56, 4, 7, 3};

    //.....

    for(int i = 0; nums[i]; i++) {
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the result was:

```
nums[0] = 12
nums[1] = 3
nums[2] = 54
nums[3] = -4
nums[4] = 56
nums[5] = 4
nums[6] = 7
nums[7] = 3
nums[8] = -427200144
nums[9] = 32765
```

I ran the code more times, and the 8th and 9th element is always kinda random... But I mean I don't even have that many numbers, what's wrong here??
Also I tried with other random numbers and sometimes it works fine...

```
    int nums[] = {2, -10, 64, 100, 22, 4};
```

```
nums[0] = 2
nums[1] = -10
nums[2] = 64
nums[3] = 100
nums[4] = 22
nums[5] = 4
```

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Edit: Meanwhile I realized this method is bad, since if the number in the array is 0, then my condition is false so the for cycle stops, but I'm curious, what's happening here, so I gonna post this anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums) / sizeof(*nums); i++) {
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);
}
```

`sizeof(nums)` is the total size of the array (in bytes).
`sizeof(*nums)` is size of one element of the array (in bytes).
Therefore, `sizeof(nums) / sizeof(*nums)` represents the number of elements and that is what should be the condition in the loop.

Another option is having a separate variable that contains number of elements in the array, but it's less convenient than the first method I described.